# Finding a recurrance of three ASCII families in a string

Tags: python, string, character, ascii, recurring

I'm trying to create a 'check' system for a password generator that will advsie whether or not three of the same types of character family are found in a row in a generated password, i.e

If the password is

> y8kpBD8zcZLKRSh1j7vwCMDQ5orR8VEP

it will find 'ZLK' etc

I first thought `lowercase_repeat = re.compile("[a-z]{3}")` would for example find three lowercase repeats, but I can't seem to understand how this works exactly.

The password generator is below:

```
import random
import re
generator = random.SystemRandom()
password_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789!@#$%^&*()'
password = ''.join(generator.choice(password_characters) for _ in range(32))
print password
```

Comment: did you enable `re.I` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Apologies, I'm not sure what you mean by this

Comment: I assume you have 4 character families: 1: lower-case alpha, 2: upper-case alpha, 3: digit, 4: punctuation. Is that correct?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, all four of those families are used

Comment: [(Insert xkcd comic about password security here).](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: @BradChristie I saw this too! Seems like a 12 char random password is as secure as a 4 random word password, but more memorable. Would be a good mini-project to do though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check for specific character sets; e.g: all uppercase, all lowercase, digit and non-alnum - you can create a non-capturing group for each set. For example:

```
import re

pattern  = '(?:[a-z]{3}|[A-Z]{3}|\d{3}|[\x20-\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7E]{3})'
password = 'y8kpBD8zcZLKRSh1j7vwCMDQ5orR8VEP!'
matches  =  re.search(pattern, password)
```

The variable `matches` returns `None` if there are no matches, indicating the password passes.

The pattern `[\x20-\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7E]` is a (probably pretty gnarly) way to catch a set of all non-alnum ascii characters (hex codes). It represents the following set:

> [space] ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~

I pulled it out of an old project, so YMMV. I'm sure there might be a more succinct way to express it - indeed, you might prefer to explicitly specify a set; e.g: `[!?#]` etc.

Quick sanity-check:

```
import re

def check_password(password):
    pattern = '(?:[a-z]{3}|[A-Z]{3}|\d{3}|[\x20-\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7E]{3})'
    return re.search(pattern, password)

passwords = ['a', 'abc', 'ABC', 'aBc', '1bc', '123']

for password in passwords:
    if check_password(password):
        print 'password failed: ', password
    else:
        print 'password passed: ', password
```

Yields:

```
password passed:  a
password failed:  abc
password failed:  ABC
password passed:  aBc
password passed:  1bc
password failed:  123
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Excellent response dude! Thank you. I understand the re.'s now :)

Comment: Also, am I right in thinking that `if check_password(password) is not None:` can be shorted to `if check_password(password) is:`